# Why use routing instead of window.location?

Tags: javascript, express

Why is Express' Routing feature a better(or worse) alternative to window.location?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? As far as I know, ExpressJS is a *server-side* framework for *responding* to web requests; its [routing feature](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) maps URLs to the code that handles responding to requests for those URLs. `window.location`, of course, is a browser property you use to tell the browser to *request* a new page from a server.

Comment: Does using a server side implementation have substantial benefits over using the browser property to change the page url?

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything. The two are completely different things that serve different purposes.

Answer (score -2):

The biggest advantage is that with route you can send parameters or define behaviours to your JS and frontend. This also makes the connection with the backend far more easier.

See the documentation for examples:
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html